# How to start eclipse with custom dropins folder (command line)?

Tags: java, eclipse, continuous-integration

How can I start eclipse from command line with my custom `dropins` folder in which I will put my plugin? I need this in order to avoid conflicts when 2 instances of eclipse want to run on the same machine with different plugin versions each.

Comment: I don't understand the need; each Eclipse installation already has its own `dropins` folder by default.

Comment: @E-Riz, I want to start 2 instances of eclipse on the same machine. One instance to point to dropins1 and the other to dropins2. Would like to give eclipse a command line parameter with the path to the dropins folder.

Comment: Copy two eclipse installation in two different folders then you will get two **dropin** folders. You can also make eclipse to show workspace location in title bar, so no confusion. Is that not simple!!

Comment: Yes, this is a solution indeed, but it is not recommended. What if I need 100 eclipse instances :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try running eclipse with the following argument:

```
-Dorg.eclipse.equinox.p2.reconciler.dropins.directory=/custom/path/to/mydropins
```

[Equinox/p2/Getting Started (dropins)](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Equinox/p2/Getting_Started#Dropins)

[Equinox p2 tests](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Equinox_p2_tests#Dropins_Reconciler)

Comment: Yes! Thank you! Just to note that this argument must be provided to `java` before the `-jar` option.

Comment: You are welcome, did you try passing the argument to the eclipse binay? It should work.

Comment: No, I need it the java way